# I am unable to capture the Response body of APi In loadrunner script

Tags: api, loadrunner

I am newly on the loadrunner , i am trying to script on that application which is API based , and Api AUTHENTICATION IS JWT TOKEN BASE,i am trying to capture the response body of the login API and i am trying to capture the access token from the body , but i am unable to capture the response body i have used multiple methods for that but i am not finding any proper solutions

**`Scripts**

```
 web_custom_request("login_2", 
        "URL=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/api/users/login", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/login", 
        "Snapshot=t334.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=application/json", 
        "Body={\"data\":{\"username\":\"******@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"******\"}}", 
        LAST);
        
        web_set_user("reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com\\******@gmail.com", "******", "reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com");
        lr_think_time(60);
        web_reg_save_param("data",
        "LB/IC={\"data\": {",
        "RB/IC=\"checker\": null}",
        LAST);
        lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{data}"));
        /* web_reg_save_param_json(
        "ParamName=userId", // Specify the parameter name to store the captured value
        "QueryString=$.data.accessToken", // Specify the JSONPath expression to extract the value
        //"Ordinal=1", // Specify the occurrence of the value if there are multiple matches
        LAST);
        lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{userId}"));*/
        

        //web_reg_save_param("ResponseBody", "LB=\"{", "RB=\"}", "Search=Body", LAST);
         //lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{ResponseBody}"));
        //web_reg_save_param("ResponseBody", "LB=\"{", "RB=\"}", "Search=Body", LAST);
            
    /*web_set_max_html_param_len("2560");
        web_reg_save_param(
    "ParamName=accessToken",
    "LB=\"accessToken\": \"",
    "RB=\"",
    "Ord=1",
    "Search=Body",
    LAST
);*/
    /*web_reg_save_param_regexp(
    "ParamName=accessToken",
    "RegExp:\"accessToken\": \"(.*?)\"",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    LAST
);*/
    
    
//web_reg_save_param("accessToken", "LB=\"accessToken\": \"", "RB=\"", "Search=Body", LAST);

//web_set_user("******@gmail.com", "******", "reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com");
//web_set_user("reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com\\******@gmail.com", lr_decrypt("4FF8D21991C9E969CD1CAD5F16400D66"),"reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com");
web_add_cookie("JSESSIONID={JSESSIONID}; DOMAIN=reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com");
//web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=accessToken", "LB=\"accessToken\":\"", "RB=\"", LAST);
//web_reg_save_param("accessTokenParam", "LB=\"accessToken\":\"", "RB=\"","Search=Body" ,"Ord=All", "NotFound=WARNING", LAST);
//lr_output_message("accessToken: %s", lr_eval_string("{ResponseBody}"));

    // Print the captured response body
    if (strlen(lr_eval_string("{ResponseBody}")) > 0) {
        lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{ResponseBody}"));
    } else {
        lr_output_message("Response Body not found");
    }

web_add_header("Authorization", "Bearer {accessToken}");

//web_add_header("Authorization", lr_eval_string("Bearer %s", lr_eval_string("{ParamName}")));
//web_add_header("Austhorization", lr_eval_string("Bearer %s", accessToken));
    web_url("users", 
        "URL=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/api/roles/users", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/login", 
        "Snapshot=t335.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        LAST);
```

**APi Response**

```
{
    "data": {
        "userId": 78,
        "username": "******@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Mudassar ",
        "middleName": "Middle",
        "lastName": "Munir",
        "empCode": "mm",
        "mobileNo": "+923477******",
        "officePhone": "+03477******",
        "officePhoneExt": "extensions",
        "userLoginTypeId": 0,
        "newOrResetPassword": null,
        "userPreferences": [
            {
                "prefKeys": "dateFormat",
                "prefValues": "DD-MM-YYYY"
            },
            {
                "prefKeys": "timeFormat",
                "prefValues": "HH:mm:ss"
            },
            {
                "prefKeys": "dateTimeFormat",
                "prefValues": "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"
            }
        ],
        "lastFailureLogin": "2023-05-25T14:25:09.488+00:00",
        "lastLogin": "2023-05-29T07:17:22.339+00:00",
        "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.d-jh1Kjy-IcZ_DwzmZna1fMzBYatbF5IupYiNNOQKop7NvwAgLPeI-B_-3jPTWV4eMUFKtubWJUf-Gwlmfxv9w",
        "refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.k4FtG20IaaYRo4uUtcgsnD1BeavFmJdMhuROHWzD_tBWSJq0n7c-jo-JyPZYdNjylkGa_WZVhN1QGuUNy0TT2g",
        "branchName": null,
        "checker": null
    },
    "message": {
        "status": "200",
        "description": "SUCCESS"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i want to capture the whole body of the APi response and from the response i wan to capture the accesstoken

Answer (score 0):

i can capture the JSON response using the following script, that code is working for me, please make sure the **web_reg_save_param_json** function call before the Endpoint.

```
 enter code here

    web_set_max_html_param_len("9999999");
        web_reg_save_param_json(
            "ParamName=userId", // Specify the parameter name to store the captured value
            "QueryString=$.data.accessToken", // Specify the JSONPath expression to extract the value
            //"Ordinal=1", // Specify the occurrence of the value if there are multiple matches
            LAST); 

web_custom_request("login_2", 
        "URL=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/api/users/login", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=https://reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com/login", 
        "Snapshot=t334.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=application/json", 
        "Body={\"data\":{\"username\":\"ch.mudassar.@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"@2023\"}}", 
        LAST);
        
        web_set_user("reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com\\ch.mudassar@gmail.com", "@2023", "reconstream-int.timestreamgroup.com");
        lr_think_time(60);
        /*web_reg_save_param("data",
        "LB/IC={\"data\": {",
        "RB/IC=\"checker\": null}",
        LAST);*/
        //lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{data}"));
    
        
        lr_output_message("Response Body: %s", lr_eval_string("{userId}"));
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am newly on the loadrunner...

Welcome to the party.  As you are new to this tool, presumably at the request of your management it would be useful to understand a few items

1. Have you attended product training, from a certified instructor, offered by the vendor or a vendor partner?  I.E., official LoadRunner classroom instruction?
2. Do you have a mentor assigned to you?  This is independent of question (1).  The softer your foundation skills and whether or not you attended training has a dramatic effect on how long your mentoring period will be.  No training, longer period.  Soft foundation skills, Longer period.   Depending on those two items, your mentoring period could be a few weeks or extend to the better part of a year.
3. Can you find performance defects without a tool?  This speaks to where value is added in the performance testing realm.   A tool can only produce data.  It is the analysis of the data and the recommendation of changes to improve the efficiency of the application which is where value is generated.  Having a mentor involved is critical to working through analysis together and ensuring you have a path to deliver value.  Side note: you do not always have to run a multi-user performance test to deliver value, particularly if the application is slow for a single user.  What will not scale for one, cannot scale for many.

> ...i have used multiple methods...

What have you tried and what have the results of your experiments been.  Understanding what you have tried and have found not to be useful has a value to us recommending items.  We understand not to traverse the path already taken that was not fruitful